# Multiple optional argument in a function

Tags: php, function

`getAllForms($data=null)`

```
getAllForms() and getAllForms("data")
```

This will work. But I want to make two optional argument in a function like this:

```
getAllForms($arg1=null,$arg2=null)

getAllForms() and getAllForms("data")
```

How can I make this possible?

Comment: use an array if you want to have multiple 'data' arguments. Else name them `$data1` and `$data2`.

Comment: yes daan i am using array both data1 and data2 are arrays . the problem is i can set only one arg optional (null)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try:

```
function getAllForms() {
    extract(func_get_args(), EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "data");
}

getAllForms();
getAllForms("a"); // $data_0 = a
getAllForms("a", "b"); // $data_0 = a $data_1 = b
getAllForms(null, null, "c"); // $data_0 = null $data_1 = null, $data_2 = c
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also try using `func_get_arg` which you can pass `n` number of arguments to a function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

**Example**

```
function foo(){
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
getAllForms($data=null,$data2=null)
```

and you call it in this mode:

```
getAllForms()
getAllForms("data")
getAllForms("data","data2")
```

The second argument have to be different name respect the first

Answer (score 1):

You already described how you would do it:

```
function getAllForms($arg1 = null, $arg2 = null)
```

Except the every variable name (including the second) has to be different.

Answer (score 1):

```
<? php
function getAllForms($data1 = null, $data2 = null)
{
    if ($data1 != null)
    {
        // do something with $data1
    }

    if ($data2 != null)
    {
        // do something with $data2
    }
}
?>

getAllForms();
getAllForms("a");
getAllForms(null, "b");
getAllForms("a", "b");
```

or

```
<? php
function getAllForms($data = null)
{
    if (is_array($data))
    {
        foreach($data as $item)
        {
            getAllForms($item);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($data != null)
        {
            // do something with data.
        }
    }
}

getAllForms();
getAllForms("a");
getAllForms(array("a"));
getAllForms(array("a", "b"));
?>
```